# Why is copy assignment called but not move assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here are my test class. VTX has both copy assignment and move assignment.
VTZ has a constructor that takes `VTS&&` to initialize its `vtx` memeber.

```
    struct VTX
    {
    int x;
    vector<int> vts;

    VTX & operator= (const VTX & other)
    {
        x = other.x;
        vts = other.vts;
        cout << "copy assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    VTX & operator= (VTX && other)
    {
        x = other.x;
        vts = std::move(other.vts);
        cout << "move assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    };

    struct VTZ
    {
    VTX vtx;
    VTZ(VTX && vvv)
    {
        vtx = vvv;
    }

    VTZ()
    {}
    };
```

Test code:

```
    int main(VOID)
    {
        VTX vtx;
        vtx.vts.resize(10);
    
        VTZ vtz(std::move(vtx));
        return 0;
    }
```

I think the move assignment of VTX will be called when VTZ is constructed. But

Output:

> copy assignment

I'm really confused why is copy assignment called but not move assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `vvv` is an [lvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) (even its type is `VTX &&`). Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are different things.

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin`
>   or `std::endl`. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>   expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

You can use `std::move` to convert it to rvalue (xvalue) expression,

```
VTZ(VTX && vvv)
{
    vtx = std::move(vvv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it another way (from the other answer currently here), this line right here:

```
vtx = vvv;
```

performs a copy, not a move.

If you want to move, you have to do something like [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456975/10957435):

```
VTZ(VTX && vvv) : vtx(std::move(vvv)) {

}
```

Or, you could [do as songyuanyao suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64745724/10957435). Either one will work.

Answer (score 0):

References are an illusion!

Although your parameter is declared `VTX&& vvv`, inside the `VTZ` constructor the actual expression `vvv` is an *lvalue* `VTX`.

The reference type doesn't actually persist.

If you want to keep moving the object along, that's fine, but you'll need to write `std::move` again.