# Pass by value or universal reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-value, forwarding-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I want to develop a small polymorphic class with type erasure and I wonder which version of the templatized constructor is better and should be used.

We can pass by value:

```
class A
{
    ...
    template< typename T >
    A( T t ) { /* create the underlying model via std::move */ }
    ...
};
```

or we can use a universal reference:

```
class A
{
    ...
    template< typename T >
    A( T &&t ) { /* create the underlying model via std::forward */ }
    ...
};
```

(The universal reference has to be enabled if for the case that `T` is not the class itself and the class is not copied). Any ideas? Both version look equal to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600499/how-to-pass-parameters-correctly) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185985/passing-by-value-vs-const-and-overloads

Comment: It certainly depends on what happens to `t` inside. But I can't actually think of any reason why you'd got with the first option. It would imply that make a local copy of `t` in the constructor -- even if you end up making a permanent copy (in a data member), why would you want a local copy?

Comment: No, in the first version you can move t.

Comment: @jogojapan read the links I posted: it actually makes sense to use pass-by-value if you're going to make a copy anyway

Comment: @stijn Not sure what exactly you refer to. But note that I am talking about function-local copies vs. copies in data members. Making a function-local copy just for the purpose of then making another copy (into the data member) doesn't make such sense. At least not at first glance.

Comment: @jogojapan I stand corrected, it wasn't clear to me you (and the OP as well maybe?) are talking about taking a function-local copy - that indeed doesn't make too much sense

Comment: But you must not make a copy. You can move the objects from the outside into the function (and you can also make a copy). This is very similar to the universal reference. Inside the function, which in this case is a constructor, you move the data into the members.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are not equivalent and sometimes one is desired over the the other one. [A **stellar** talk by Nicolai Josuttis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o&t=0s) is an hour worth of talking just about this. I highly recommend watching it at least once.

Personally, unless you encounter a special case, where conversions are expensive and you want to avoid temporaries as much as possible, I would suggest just  passing by value and `std::move`ing the argument.

Case where `T&&` is more efficient:

```
struct foo {
    std::string bar;

    template <typename T>
    foo(T&& t)
        :bar(std::forward<T>(t)){}
};
```

versus:

```
struct foo {
    std::string bar;

    foo(std::string t)
        :bar(std::move(t)){}
};
```

when you do:

```
int main() {
    foo f("some char*");
}
```

In the first case (perfect forwarding) you simply construct a `std::string` with `const char*` argument. In the second case, you construct one temporary (`t` from `"some char*"`) and one empty `std::string` object, then you apply one move operation. It's not the end of the world, but the first version is simply more efficient.

To be absolutely clear about performance:

- The first version uses *1 allocation*
- the second version uses *1 allocation and 1 move*

and by *move* I don't mean `std::move`, since it generates no code (it's just a cast). By *move* I mean *the code that needs to be execuded that actually moves from the string, which is a part of `std::string(std::string&&)`*.

Once again - the above example was based on the talk I linked at the beginning of the answer. It's **really** worth watching.