# Is it better to pass-by-value and then move-construct or to pass-by-reference and then copy-construct

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 in a constructor, is it better to do:

```
class A
{
  A(std::string str) : mStr(std::move(str)) {}
  std::string mStr;  
}
```

or to do

```
class A
{
  A(const std::string& str) : mStr(str) {}
  std::string mStr;  
}
```

In which cases can copy elision occur when an rvalue is passed in to the constructor?

Comment: A smart enough compiler can elide all of these if the argument passed in is not inspected again. That's the same rule as ever: the as-if rule. If your code can't tell the difference, the compiler can do it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I am not so sure here, the copy constructor of `std::string` has side effects (memory allocation), and copy elision is only allowed to ignore the possibility of side effects in a very narrow set of circumstances (which I believe only include returning from a function).

Comment: @MatthieuM. unless you override `new`, those side-effects are not observable. The as-if rule supersedes the copy elisions rules, because the as-if rule allows everything.

Comment: [Want speed? Pass by value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) It's not a universal rule of course, but it does answer your question - favouring pass-by-value + move.

Comment: @MatthieuM. C++14 makes memory allocation optimizable. Specifically - from [N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3936.pdf) - 5.3.4/8 "A new-expression **may** obtain storage for the object by calling an allocation function (3.7.4.1).", and 5.3.4/10 "An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function (18.6.1.1, 18.6.1.2)."

Comment: Related: [Is the pass-by-value-and-then-move construct a bad idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21035417/341970) or [When is overloading pass by reference (l-value and r-value) preferred to pass-by-value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18303287/341970) or [c++11 optimal parameter passing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10472179/341970) or [Passing by value vs const & and && overloads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14185985/341970)

Comment: @Casey: That's great, I know LLVM (at least) took the liberty already but it's great to see it official. Of course, it does not solve the issue of opaque copy constructors...

Answer (score 1):

You should do "pass by value and then move construct" if your type's move constructor is cheap, and use "Pass by reference and then copy construct" otherwise.

## For lvalues

### Pass by value and then move construct

You will be doing one copy followed by one move.

### Pass by reference and then copy construct

You will be doing one copy

## For Rvalues

### Pass by value and then move construct

In the best case (when the rvalue is a temporary expression) you will be doing no copy/no move, followed by a move.

In the normal case (when the rvalue is not a temporary expression) you will be doing a move followed by another move.

### Pass by reference and then copy construct

You will be doing one copy

Comment: Another good point for pass by value then move is the ability to trigger possible throwing code before the function call and add the noexcept qualifier to it.

Comment: Should mention perfect forwarding (manual or magic)

Comment: @yakk ohh please go ahead. I didnt want to write a large answer.