# Move constructors and `std::array`

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

According to N3485 §23.3.2.2:

> (...) the implicit move constructor and move assignment operator for **array** require that T be **MoveConstructible** or **MoveAssignable**, respectively.

So, `std::array` supports move semantics if the type of its elements does. Great!

However, what does this really mean? I tend to picture this type as a safer version of an array providing an STL-compliant interface but, if this is true, then how can an `std::array` move-construct its elements? Can I do the same with an ordinary array?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> However, what does this really mean?

It means that, if the element type is movable, then so is the array type.

```
std::array<movable, 42> move_from = {...};
std::array<movable, 42> move_to = std::move(move_from); // moves all the elements
```

> I tend to picture this type as a safer version of an array providing an STL-compliant interface

Not really. It's a wrapper for an array, giving it the same semantics as an aggregate class - including the ability to copy and move it.

> how can an `std::array` move-construct its elements?

In exactly the same way as any other aggregate. Its implicit move-constructor will move-construct all its members, including the elements of any member arrays.

> Can I do the same with an ordinary array?

Only if you wrap it in a class type, as `std::array` does.

Comment: *"Only if you wrap it in a class type"* So it is the fact that it's a user-defined type what allows this behavior... Interesting.

Comment: @faranwath: Indeed - specifically, the fact that user-defined aggregate types have implicitly generated move constructors.

Answer (score 25):

Moving a `std::array` is different from moving a `std::vector`. When moving one `std::vector` into another, it's (sometimes*) possible to simply re-target the internal pointers and avoid manipulating the elements at all.

With `std::array`, this is of course not possible - its elements have automatic storage duration, they are literally contained inside the object. However, each individual one of them can still be moved, and that's what the move operations on `std::array` do**.

<sup>* Assuming the allocators are compatible and don't prohibit this operation</sup>

<sup>** That's also what you get with `std::vector` when the buffer can't just be re-owned by the destination vector.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

The default move constructor for a (non-union) class performs a member-wise move. Moving a raw array data member means moving each of the array's elements, see [class.copy]/15.

Therefore, you can move a raw array by putting it inside a class:

```
struct wrap
{
    std::string arr[25];
};

auto w = wrap();
auto m = std::move(w); // moves the 25 `std::string`s
```

You can also manually invoke the move constructor of the elements, for example:

```
std::string a[3] = { /*...*/ };
std::string b[3] = {std::move(a[0]), std::move(a[1]), std::move(a[2])};
```

It is not specified if `std::array` contains a raw array. However, it does contain data members of the `value_type`, since it's guaranteed to be an aggregate. Those data members will be moved as described above when invoking the move constructor.

If the data members of a `std::array` are not MoveConstructible, instantiating its move constructor will fail.

Comment: *"Therefore, you can move a raw array by putting it inside a class"* The same was pointed out by Mike Seymour, I wasn't aware of it -- although now that I think about it, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using "placement `new`".  You'll find plenty of [questions on placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20placement-new) already answered with many further details.

This one looks like it has a complete example:

- [Why is this code trying to call the copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8991874/103167)

Comment: I didn't think of it!