# aggregate type and move semantic: references needed

Tags: c++, move

Starting with this snippet:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

class wrap {
   public:
    std::array<std::string, 3> a;
    wrap(std::array<std::string, 3>&& input) : a(std::move(input)){};
};
```

I read on several sources that an `std::array` has no move constructor which would make no sense, yet syntax above implies that its not the `std::array` that is moved but its element.
I couldn't found a word about that in cppreference (for instance) and finally stumbled on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613991/move-constructors-and-stdarray).

It basically says that:

> In exactly the same way as any other aggregate. Its implicit move-constructor will move-construct all its members, including the elements of any member arrays.

What would be the standard reference? The best I found is [n2904 Defining default copy and move](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2904.pdf) and [Move constructors and `std::array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613991/move-constructors-and-stdarray), regarding `std::array` only.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#14

Comment: From cpp reference: [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (constructor implicitly declared) and [Implicitly-defined_move_constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-defined_move_constructor).

Comment: @Jarod42 OK _For non-union class types (class and struct), the move constructor performs full member-wise move of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using direct initialization with an xvalue argument._

Comment: question answered. Thanks