# Eliminating copying of function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-elision

I am writing a custom memory allocator. If possible, I want to make object creation function like this to abstract creation procedure completely.

```
template<typename T>
class CustomCreator
{
    virtual T& createObject(T value) __attribute__((always_inline))
    { 
        T* ptr = (T*)customAlloc();
        new (ptr) T(value);
        return *ptr;
    }
}
```

But this causes copying. Is there a way to force to eliminate copying in this case?

Here's my current testing code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct AA
{
    inline static void test(AA aa) __attribute__((always_inline))
    {
        AA* ptr =   new AA(aa);
        delete ptr;
    }

    AA(AA const& aa)
    {
        printf("COPY!\n");
    }
    AA(int v)
    {
        printf("CTOR!\n");
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    AA::test(AA(77));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass the `value` as `T&`, `T const&`, `T&&`, `T const&&`, but it still copies. 
I expected optimizer will eliminate function frame, so the function parameter can be deduced into an R-value, but I still see `COPY!` message.

I also tried C++11 forwarding template, but I couldn't use it because it cannot be a virtual function.

My compiler is Clang included in Xcode. (clang-425.0.28) And optimization level is set to `-Os -flto`.

### Update (for later reference)

I wrote extra tests, and checked generated LLVM IR with `clang -Os -flto -S -emit-llvm  -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp;` options. What I could observe are: (1) function frames always can be get eliminated. (2) if large object (4096 byte) passed by value, it didn't get eliminated. (3) Passing r-value reference using `std::move` works well. (4) if I don't make move-constructor, compiler mostly fall back to copy-constructor.

Comment: to avoid copying, you have to implement move constructor

Comment: Your code is not a situation where the copy can be elided.  Copies are basically only elided for return values from functions.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see, did you expect `new AA(aa);` to move?  Or did you expect the copy to be elided altogeather?

Comment: You're also making the function virtual, which means dodging copying from copy-elision becomes closer to impossible since you're expecting runtime dispatch (how can the compiler know before it finishes making the program what to do?)

Comment: Wait, there's no virtual functions here... Is `createObject` supposed to be `virtual`?

Comment: @MooingDuck My mistake. It was a virtual instance method.

Comment: I updated `createObject` function to be proper and realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
You expected the optimizer to eliminate the function frame, but it can't, because (1) that function isn't a valid case for RVO to cheat and skip the copy constructor entirely, and (2) Your function has side effects.  Namely, writing `copy` to the screen.  So the optimizer can't optimize out the copy, because the code says it must write `copy` out twice.  What I would do is remove the `printf` call, and check the assembly.  Most likely, if it's simple, it *is* being optimized out.

Second:
If the members copy constructors can have side effects (such as allocating memory), then most likely you're right that it isn't being optimized out.  However, you can tell it to *move* members rather than copying them, which is probably what you expected.  For this to work you'll need to make sure your class has a move constructor alongside your copy constructor.

```
inline static void test(AA aa) __attribute__((always_inline))
{
    AA* ptr =   new AA(std::move(aa));
    delete ptr;
}
```

Third:
In reality, even that isn't really what you want.  What you probably want is something more like perfect forwarding, which will just directly pass the parameters to the constructor without making copies of ANYTHING. This means even with the optimizer disabled entirely, your code is still avoiding copies.  (Note that this may not apply to your situation, templates cannot be `virtual` like this, unless it's specialized)

```
template<class ...types>
inline static void test(types&&... values) __attribute__((always_inline))
{
    AA* ptr =   new AA(std::forward<types>(values)...);
    delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: Awww, you beat me to it. D:

Comment: @ThePhD: Thanks, I'd shortened the names incorrectly.  All the code is guessed, there's probably more errors

Comment: I though compiler to be more aggressive, but maybe I have to check the assemblies!

Comment: *"(2) Your function has side effects. Namely, writing copy to the screen. So the optimizer can't optimize out the copy, because the code says it must write copy out twice."* - A constructor having side effects is still not a valid reason not to apply RVO. Optimizing out side effects via copy elision is explicitly allowed by the standard.

Comment: @ChristianRau: "(1) that function isn't a valid case for RVO to cheat and skip the copy constructor entirely"  That's why there were two seperate points, one for RVO, and one for generic optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't your copy-constructor explicitly called in line `AA* ptr =   new AA(aa);`? If you want to avoid copying initializing value, you should do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct
    AA
    {   inline static void test(AA aa) __attribute__((always_inline))
        {
            AA* ptr = new AA(std::move(aa));
            delete ptr;
        }

        inline static void test(AA&& aa) __attribute__((always_inline))
        {
            AA* ptr = new AA(std::move(aa));
            delete ptr;
        }

        AA(AA const& aa)
        {
            printf("COPY!\n");
        }

        AA(AA const&& aa) // Move constructors are not default here - you have to declare one
        {
            printf("MOVE!\n");
        }

        AA(int v)
        {
            printf("CTOR!\n");
            xx  =   v;
        }

        int xx  =   55;
    };

    AA::test(AA(77));
    return 0;
}
```

Problems:

- Conditions allowing [default move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor) are quite tight, you are better off writing one yourself.
- If you pass value along (**even a temporary one**) you still need std::move to to pass it even further without creating a copy.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's solve your `A&&` move problem. You can get a move constructor by making a move constructor (or declaring it default) (or letting the compiler generate one), and making sure you call `std::move` on `aa` when you pass it through: [Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=685d0d02b149f7cd19b73819d633511a-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59).

The same will apply to any virtual instance function you are working with. I've also included the forwarding variadic version in the example as well, just in case you'd like a reference on how to do that as well (notice all the arguments are `std::forward`ed to their next calls).

In either case, this seems like a question spawned from a serious case of `XY`, that is: you're trying to solve a problem you've created with your current design. I don't know why you need to create objects through instance methods on a pre-existing object (factory-type creation?), but it sounds messy. In either case, the above should help you out enough to get your going. Just make sure if you're moving parameters, to always wrap the `&&` item with a `std::move` (or `std::forward` if you're working with universal references and template parameters).

Comment: Yes I was intended factory method. This function is a primitive for it. And I wanted to add more allocation algorithms later by subclassing. So it became `virtual`.