# in-placement constructor std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, in-place

Can I create vector that contains elements that are noncopyable and don't have a default constructor in C++11?

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct value {
    value() = delete;
    ~value() = default;

    value(value const&) = delete;
    value& operator =(value const&) = delete;

    explicit value(int i) : i_(i) {}
private:
    int i_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<value> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(7);
}
```

and here I want to create 10 values and each to value ctor pass the integer 7 ...

```
std::vector< value > v(in-place, 10, 7)
```

Why wasn't the C++11 placement construction form added to this std::vector constructor

Errors pasted from [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=704fadd6c01d2fd2b97392966c11fef0-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51):

```
+ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = value; _Args = {value}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<value*> _ForwardIterator = value*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<value*> _ForwardIterator = value*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<value*> _ForwardIterator = value*; _Tp = value]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1142:29:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::move_iterator<value*> _Tp = value; _Alloc = std::allocator<value> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = value*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:75:70:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = value; _Alloc = std::allocator<value> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:24:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘value::value(const value&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
main.cpp:11:5: error: declared here
     value(value const&) = delete;
     ^
```

Comment: All the answers so far assume that the items are (or can sensibly be made to be) moveable.  I'd like to see an answer without this assumption.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question - why don't you ask it?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get errors is that using `emplace_back` on a `std::vector` requires the element type to be at least *MoveConstructible*. This is needed if the vector needs to grow and reallocate its elements.

Add a *move constructor* to you struct and you will be able to use it in your code (the default implementation will suffice for your code).

```
value(value&&) = default;
```

The compiler will not implicitly generate a default move constructor for your struct as you have declared your own *copy constructor*, `value(value const&) = delete` (`=delete` and `=default` count as user-declared), as well as a *copy assignment operator* and a *destructor*.

For more info about the rules of implicit move constructor generation, look here: [Why no default move-assignment/move-constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor)

---

Using `std::vector`'s constructor of the form `std::vector(size_t count, const T& value)` copies the  values into the vector, and requires the element type to be *CopyConstructible*.

Comment: Declaring a constructor does not in general suppress generation of the default move constructor: declaring a *copy* constructor does suppress generation of a default move constructor (§12.8p9).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the resizing etc. *can* all be handled with move instead of copy constructor/assignment, if you define it (whatever cppreference says).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct value {
    int i_;

    explicit value(int i) : i_(i)   {std::cout<<"value::value("  <<i_<<")\n"; }
    value(value &&src) : i_(src.i_) {std::cout<<"value::value(&&"<<i_<<")\n"; }
    value(value const&) = delete;
    value& operator=(value const&) = delete;
    value& operator=(value &&src) {
        i_ = src.i_;
        std::cout << "value::=(&&" << i_ << ")\n";
        return *this;
    }
    value() = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<value> v;
    v.reserve(1);
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(3);
}
```

works fine:

```
value::value(1)   <-- emplace_back(1)
value::value(2) 
value::value(&&1) <-- emplace_back(2) inc. resize & move 1
value::value(3)
value::value(&&1)
value::value(&&2) <-- emplace_back(3) inc. resize & move 1,2
```

---

### Motivation for the requirement

Before move support, if a vector's elements were non-copyable, it would be unable to resize itself (or erase items, or fulfill quite a lot of its interface).

Comment: std::array is only static size, if I need dynamic size I can't use it.

Comment: I missed that you hadn't defined move constructor & assignment, given you're asking about C++11. That's all you need.

Comment: for emplace_back  needn't move ctor and assigment, if enough memory already exists, so why I should defined them?

Comment: if the vector has to resize dynamically, it needs to move your already-emplaced items to a new allocated block.

Comment: Note that even if the move code is never _called_, it still needs to be _instantiated_. Even if the compiler is smart enough to analyze your run-time constraint at compile time, and optimize that code out, it still needs to be legally instantiatable.

Comment: This all assumes the items are (or can sensibly be made to be) "movable".  What if they aren't?   Seems to me a valid use case is: create an empty vector, reserve it to size n, emplace_back n items.   This should not invoke any copying or moving, right?  But it seems I can't do this unless I define a move constructor that will never be called (so I can make it throw a fatal runtime error, I guess).

Comment: You're entirely free to write a runtime-sized-but-non-growable container if you want - the standard library just doesn't provide one. `std::vector` has _lots_ of methods that can't be instantiated at all if elements are neither copyable nor moveable. At the very least it would need to provide a separate _non-growing_ overload of `emplace_back` that somehow returned an error, to avoid trying to instantiate the resizing code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put objects that aren't copyable or default-constructible in a `vector` in C++11, if they are movable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct value {
    value() = delete;
    ~value() = default;

    value(value const&) = delete;
    value& operator =(value const&) = delete;

    // Move construction and assignment
    value(value&&) = default;
    value& operator =(value&&) = default;

    explicit value(int i) : i_(i) {}
private:
    int i_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<value> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(7);
}
```

But you can't use the constructor that fills such a vector with copies of a given value - since the values are not copyable. Similarly, you can't grow a vector of such objects with `resize`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a move constructor and then use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
struct value
{
    ...

    value(value && obj) : i_(obj.i_)
    {
    }

    or 

    value(value && obj) = default;

    ...
};

std::vector<value> v;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   v.emplace_back(7);
```