# Should i make a class instead of the repetitive get/set statements?

Tags: c++, class, optimization, accessor

Consider the following code (which is a simplified version of the original one):

```
#include <string>

namespace my
{
    class CType;
}

class my::CType
{
private:

    std::string simple_name;

public:

    explicit CType(std::string simple_name)
    : simple_name{std::move(RequireIdentifier(simple_name))} // Duplicate Code
    {
    }
    std::string get_simple_name() const
    {
        return simple_name;
    }
    void set_simple_name(std::string value)
    {
        simple_name = std::move(RequireIdentifier(value)); // Duplicate Code
    }
};
```

The `RequireIdentifier` function returns a reference to the `value` where the `value` is not empty otherwise it will throw an `std::invalid_argument` exception.

I have too many classes which are similar to the `CType` class definition, all of them have a private member variable of type `std::string` and subsequently they check its value to be not empty with the following expression:

```
std::move(RequireIdentifier(value))
```

Here is my problem, it is repeated in all of that classes! suppose that i have 10 classes similar to `CType`, then there should be 20=2*10 expressions like the above case! i don't want to repeat a similar code in all of the 20 places of code! it seams wrong.

I think that i should define a new class type:

```
class my::Identifier
{
private:

    std::string name;

public:

    explicit Identifier(std::string name)
    : name{std::move(RequireIdentifier(name))} // Duplicate Code
    {
    }
    std::string get() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    void set(std::string value)
    {
        name = std::move(RequireIdentifier(value)); // Duplicate Code
    }
};
```

And then change the definition of `CType` class as the following code:

```
class my::CType
{
private:

    Identifier simple_name;

public:

    explicit CType(Identifier simple_name)
    : simple_name{std::move(simple_name)}
    {
    }
    Identifier get_simple_name() const
    {
        return simple_name;
    }
    void set_simple_name(Identifier value)
    {
        simple_name = std::move(value);
    }
};
```

BTW, i can't avoid the repetitive `std::move` section and that is not a problem.

But if i don't overload the `=` operator of the `Identifier` class and if i don't declare an implicit conversion to the `std::string` for the `Identifier` class, then the `Identifier` class will not work as a `string` class. Then isn't it a bad choice of design? What is the proper way to avoid the repetitive code in such case (AFAIK, we shouldn't subclass from any STL container)?

**EDIT**: the `RequireIdentifier` function is defined as the following code:

```
inline std::string& my::RequestIdentifier(std::string& value)
{
    for(char c : value)
    {
        if(!isalnum(c) && c != '_')
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{""};
        }
    }

    return value;
}

inline std::string& my::RequireIdentifier(std::string& value) // HERE IS IT
{
    if(value.empty())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument{""};
    }
    else
    {
        return my::RequestIdentifier(value);
    }
}
```

## Conclusion

As you can see if i put the "extraction" of the underlying string in my `CType` class (as mentioned in the accepted answer by *Tony D*), and if i want to work with the `string` type, then i have to call the `get` and `set` member functions of the `Identifier` class in all of my 10 classes repetitively as i had called the `RequireIdentifier` function. Therefore making a class just for eliminating one function call redundancy, techinically is not a good approach.

On the other hand and regardless of code redundancy, i should declare `Identifer` class if i really think that it is a new type that the `string` type cannot represent it well, and i can declare an *implicit* user-defined constructor for it to make it compatible with the `string` type, and finally the purpose of the `Identifier` class is not to be a `get` and `set` accessor for the `string` type, its purpose is to be a new type.

Comment: What is the reason function of `RequireIdentifier`? It seems a bit strange that it returns something you then attempt to move from. What happens if you move from the same lvalue twice?

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is defined to avoid the repetition of checking if a string is empty. I included its definition.

Comment: A class with pure set/get functions are over engineered, just a struct should be enough? or just a string should be enough?

Comment: @billz: that is my problem, i need to check that the string is not empty and can't just allow a string that can be empty!

Comment: @ccsadegh just write a free function for that should be sufficient?

Comment: @billz: RequireIdentifier is a free function, but i had to repeat it every time when i have to set that private member variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It does, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor

Comment: @ccsadegh Sorry, I somehow saw a user defined copy constructor in there. I better go back to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if i don't overload the = operator of the Identifier class and if i don't declare an implicit conversion to the std::string for the Identifier class, then the Identifier class will not work as a string class. Then isn't it a bad choice of design? What is the proper way to avoid the repetitive code in such case?

So... just put the "extraction" of the underlying `string` in your `CType` class:

```
class my::CType
{
  private:
    Identifier simple_name;

  public:
    explicit CType(Identifier simple_name)
      : simple_name{std::move(simple_name)}
    { }

    std::string get_simple_name() const
    {
        return simple_name.get();
    }

    void set_simple_name(std::string value)
    {
        simple_name.set(std::move(value));
    }
};
```

UPDATE: as requested in comments, below - an illustration of using a `check_invariants()` function.  There's still some redundancy, but you can repeat an arbitrary number of checks without further modifying each mutating function.

```
class my::CType
{
  private:
    std::string simple_name;

    void check_invariants()
    {
        if (!is_identifier(simple_name))
            throw std::invalid_argument("empty identifier);
    }

  public:
    explicit CType(std::string simple_name)
      : simple_name{std::move(simple_name))
    {
         check_invariants();
    }
    std::string get_simple_name() const
    {
        return simple_name;
    }
    void set_simple_name(std::string value)
    {
        simple_name = std::move(value);
        check_invariants();
    }
};
```

...with...

```
bool is_identifier(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() &&
        (isalpha(s[0]) || s[0] == '_') &&
        std::all_of(s.begin() + 1, s.end(), [](char c) { return isalnum(c) || c == '_'; });
}
```

Comment: Do you encourage to define a new class for repetitive get/set statements?

Comment: @ccsadegh These things are a matter of balance... defining a class to enforce invariants like this is often reasonable, though eliminating one line redundancy isn't compelling.  A notable alternative is adding a `check_invariants()` function that you call at the end of the constructor(s) and assignment operator that can check any number of such conditions.  Further, `get` and `set` are often indicative of an "anti-pattern" - it might be that such names could be keys in a map storing the values or any of many other models - it's hard to know without understanding your application....

Comment: Would you include an example about check_invariants() function?

Comment: Thanks, the `check_invariants` function in this case seems good where the type of the member variable has a default ctor.

Comment: @ccsadegh: that's not even required, as the member variable can still be initialised in the initialisation list before the invariant/s is/are checked.

Comment: @ccsadegh I appreciate your efforts to create an answer you're happy with by editing further opinions into mine, but you should really post your own answer or make your own summary as an edit to the question.  As is, I have my name to content I've not written and don't necessarily agree with.  Edits should focus on correcting clear and significant accidental errors or omissions, adding links to already-mentioned content, fixing broken formatting so content appears as clearly intended.  Or, when you have points to make you should make them as comments and let me decide whether to edit them in.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, and i should edit my question. Thank you for making me aware.

Comment: @ccsadegh: no worries - it's not that anything specific you'd written bothered me - just a tip for "SO harmony" :-).  Cheers.