# default/delete move constructor and assignment with the existence of RVO

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value, rvalue-reference, return-value-optimization

I guess that this question has been asked but I simply haven't found similar answers yet.

Let's see a contrived example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

#define LOG \
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << str_ << '\t' << this << std::endl;

    class Test {
     public:
      Test(std::string const &str) : str_(str) { LOG; }
      Test(Test const &rhs) : str_(rhs.str_) { LOG; }
      // Test(Test &&rhs) = delete;
      Test(Test &&rhs) : str_(std::move(rhs.str_)) { LOG; }
      // Test &operator=(Test const &rhs) {
      // if (this == &rhs) return this;
      //   str_ = rhs.str_;
      //   LOG;
      //   return *this;
      // }
      // Test &operator=(Test &&rhs) = delete;
      // Test &operator=(Test &&rhs) {
      //   assert(this != &rhs);
      //   str_.swap(rhs.str_);
      //   LOG;
      //   return *this;
      // }
      ~Test() { LOG; }
      static Test gen() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return Test("DUMMY");
      }

     private:
      std::string str_;
    };

    int main(void) {
      {
        Test test = Test("test");
        Test t(test);
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      { Test t0(Test("t0")); }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      {
        Test t1 = Test{"t1"};
        /// t1 = Test("t2");
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      { Test t(Test::gen()); }
      return 0;
    }
```

#### When I explicitly `Test(Test &&test) = delete;` and compiled this segment with `clang-3.4` it emit errors like below:

```
simple.cc:29:12: error: call to deleted constructor of 'Test'
    return Test("DUMMY");
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
simple.cc:12:3: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
  Test(Test &&rhs) = delete;
```

#### When I customize the move constructor like the one in the src, it compiles. However

However **NO move constructor is even called**(here is the result):

```
Test::Test(const std::string &) test    0x7fff2e513448
Test::Test(const Test &) test   0x7fff2e513430
Test::~Test() test  0x7fff2e513430
Test::~Test() test  0x7fff2e513448

Test::Test(const std::string &) t0  0x7fff2e513428
Test::~Test() t0    0x7fff2e513428

Test::Test(const std::string &) t1  0x7fff2e513410
Test::~Test() t1    0x7fff2e513410

static Test Test::gen()
Test::Test(const std::string &) DUMMY   0x7fff2e5133f8
Test::~Test() DUMMY 0x7fff2e5133f8
```

Later I found it may result from `return value optimization` so I compiled again with `-fno-elide-constructors`. This time the result is as below:

```
Test::Test(const std::string &) test    0x7fff9590cd90
Test::Test(Test &&) test    0x7fff9590cd98
Test::~Test()   0x7fff9590cd90
Test::Test(const Test &) test   0x7fff9590cd78
Test::~Test() test  0x7fff9590cd78
Test::~Test() test  0x7fff9590cd98

Test::Test(const std::string &) t0  0x7fff9590cd68
Test::Test(Test &&) t0  0x7fff9590cd70
Test::~Test()   0x7fff9590cd68
Test::~Test() t0    0x7fff9590cd70

Test::Test(const std::string &) t1  0x7fff9590cd48
Test::Test(Test &&) t1  0x7fff9590cd50
Test::~Test()   0x7fff9590cd48
Test::~Test() t1    0x7fff9590cd50

static Test Test::gen()
Test::Test(const std::string &) DUMMY   0x7fff9590ccf0
Test::Test(Test &&) DUMMY   0x7fff9590cd28
Test::~Test()   0x7fff9590ccf0
Test::Test(Test &&) DUMMY   0x7fff9590cd30
Test::~Test()   0x7fff9590cd28
Test::~Test() DUMMY 0x7fff9590cd30
```

It invoked `move constructors` as expected. However explicitly deleting `move constructor` still causes the program to fail to compile.

### my questions:

- Why it reports errors when the `move constructor` is deleted? **Why DIDN'T it match `copy constructor` instead(although not exact match as the `move constructor` did)?** `C++03` has no rvalue-reference, what was the compilers solutions then? In addition, I read [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819936/why-no-default-move-assignment-move-constructor) and I suppose that in my case since I specified *a user-declared copy constructor* the *move constructor* **shouldn't** be *default*(thereby it should be deleted?) I also realized that [n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) has similar writes about this. Is clang accord with the standard?
- What has `Return Value Optimization` done here? <strike>Especially, why `Test::Test(const Test &)` is called rather than `Test::Test(Test &&)`?</strike>(Sorry I didn't notice that there's only one copy constructor invocation in the RVO version results)
- I also noticed similar issues for `move assignment`(if it's deleted, then compiles complains error). So what's going on here?

Comment: Deleted special member functions participate in overload resolution, and a move or a copy constructor is required, even if RVO elides the copies.

Comment: If you provide a copy ctor but no move ctor, the move ctor is *not* deleted. It is instead *not declared at all.*

Comment: The program must be valid without the optimisation, regardless of whether the optimisation is performed.

Comment: @dyp remove that question, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Angew But what's the meaning of `not declared`? Will not declared move constructor be invoked?

Comment: @HongxuChen: No, a function that neither exists nor is said to exist cannot be invoked.

Comment: @MooingDuck So `deleted` is not the same as `not declared`? Why so ood?(I was thinking that if a function is not user-defined nor default then it was deleted.)

Comment: @HongxuChen A deleted function is declared, but has no body - it is an error to call it. A not declared function simply does not exist. Big and important difference.

Comment: @MooingDuck So will `not declared` function be generated in the executable?

Comment: @HongxuChen: No, a not declared function is never mentioned in the code, and doesn't exist in any way, shape, or form, period.  _It does not exist_.  a `deleted` function "exists", but reports an error any time you try to use it.  (You're right that it's very odd and stupid and I think `deleted` is poorly named.)

Comment: Note that the rules changed in C++14: Here, the move constructor will be implicitly declared, implicitly defined as deleted and *not* take part in overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Even when the compiler elides a copy or move, the language still requires that the function exist and be accessible. This is to make the program always consistently compile regardless of whether a compiler elides or doesn't elide a particular copy/move.
2. `test` has a name so it's automatically an lvalue and cant' be moved from without an explicit `std::move`. Thus the compiler has to copy `test` into `t`.
3. I don't understand what you expect to happen - I don't see any reason it wouldn't call the move assignment operator.

The short version is, if the move or copy constructor are *notionally called* before optimization, they have to exist and be accessible. That's just the requirement of the language standard.

Comment: 1. i still have problems understanding that `move constructor` implicit rule` in the standard. Will this default move constructor be generated for the RVO version?

Comment: 2. just remove the 2nd part of the question. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: 3. This case is similar to constructor, when `move assignment` is deleted, the compiler emits errors.

Comment: Basically i don't know why `move constructor/assignment` should exist even when they are not called FINALLY?

Comment: And when exactly the move constructor will be removed from the generated class?

Comment: @HongxuChen Never; it will just never be added.