# std::move(std::array) g++ vs visual-c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I had some problem implementing the move constructor for an element in my std::array in my project in visual studio 2013.

So I tried making a minimal example in notepad++ that I compiled with g++ 5.3.0.
Only to find that in g++ I could do what I was trying

example g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&)
    {
        cout << "copy constructed" << endl;
    }
    A(A&&)
    {
        cout << "move constructed" << endl;
    }
};

class B{
public:
    B(array<A, 2>&& a)
      : m_a(std::move(a))
    {}
private:
    array<A, 2> m_a;
};

int main(){
    A foo;
    cout << "=========1===========" << endl;
    array<A, 2> a = { { foo, std::move(foo) } };
    cout << "=========2===========" << endl;
    B b(std::move(a));
    cout << "=========3===========" << endl;
    array<A, 2> a_second = std::move(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> =========1===========
>   copy constructed
>   move constructed
>   =========2===========
>   move constructed
>   move constructed
>   =========3===========
>   move constructed
>   move constructed

When I tried the (practically) the same code in visual studio 2013 the result was different:

Output:

> =========1===========
>   copy constructed
>   move constructed
>   =========2===========
>   copy constructed
>   copy constructed
>   =========3===========
>   copy constructed
>   copy constructed

How can I use the move constructor in visual c++ and why does visual c++ refuse to use him here?

Comment: OT, did you really need to post two code samples because of unnecessary `stdafx.h` and `_tmain`?

Comment: [Off Topic]`B(array<A, 2>& a) : m_a(std::move(a))` is not how you want to move something into a object.  You leave the object in the call site moved from without any indication that it is.

Comment: @LogicStuff I wanted to show that I was not doing anything different.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll edit in a better version, I cycled trough alot of constructors to find something that works this is the latest one but indeed not a good interface.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker I indeed use a lot of unnecesary std's since I normally do not use 'using namespace std' as of the '\n' , I didn't know that would do the same. Yet I do not use cout anymore outside of test programs, also endl is the same amount of characters and subjectively easier to type.

Comment: @turoni -- I wasn't objecting to `std::`; it's the right way to use things from the standard library. And `'\n'` **doesn't** do the same thing as `std::endl`; it does less -- it starts a new line. (That's a hint: read about what `std::endl` actually does and decide whether you need it)

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker that is indeed a usefull distinction, [info explaining difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in MSVS 2013.  MSVS 2013 [does not generate implicit move constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581262/default-move-constructor-in-visual-studio-2013-update-3).  If you run it in a MSVS 2015 or 2017 you get the same output.

---

I would also like to point out that

```
B(array<A, 2>& a) : m_a(std::move(a))
```

Is not how you want to move an object into `B`.  If you want `B` to take over the array you should have

```
B(array<A, 2>&& a) : m_a(std::move(a))
```

This means that instead of using

```
B b(a);
```

you have to use

```
B b(std::move(a));
```

and now you can clearly see that `a` has been moved from in `main`.

Comment: I just edited in better constructor for B.
Is there any way I can get the same result in MSV2013?

Comment: @turoni Unfortunately no.  It just isn't built to work correctly.

Comment: @turoni You can write a type wrapping `std::array`, like inherited, and manually implement the move constructor.  MSVC2013 never writes a proper move ctor for you and doesn't let you `noexcept`.  MSVC2017 requires a proper `noexcept` to work in `std::vector`s properly.  It is a large pain.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio 2013 isn't fully compatible with C++11. Move support for std containers is one of those "not fully implemented" parts.
Your example works fine for the latest version of VS2017, see [at Rextester](http://rextester.com/DMAC64783).

P.S. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) you can get detailed information about support for C++ features in various compilers.